# Open source test suite for Java List API implementations?

Tags: java, collections, test-suite

I just wrote a `WeakArrayList<E>` class, which implements `List<E>`,  with `WeakReference<E>`s to the elements, and appropriate synchronizations.

I have every reason to believe that a through test suite will be much larger and complicated then my class is.

Is there a (free) test suite for `List`, `ArrayList` and `Map`?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Depending on your particular implementation, if your `WeakArrayList` class violates the List spec, it (predictably) will fail the test suites.  This really depends on how you tried to work weak references into the `List` interface.

Comment: Yes, I know Louis. My implementation will conform to a `List<E>`. In particular, it will behave exactly like the SE `ArrayList<E>`
 as long as there are (other) strong references to all items in the WeakArrayList, and various other conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Google Collections has a very elaborate library of collection test suites, but it is not usable out-of-the-box for external classes nor JUnit 4. I forked http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk (A subset of Guava), And I converted the tests into their own library. I had to modify some classes, and add others so that it would work correctly with Generics in subclasses, and to resolve some other issues. I may put it on GitHub or something if I can determine that it won't violate any licenses.